# overlapping widgets gtk

Tags: gtk

How can i make widgets overlap one another.

Lower most should be image, rest above can be other widgets like buttons.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Subclass the larger(parent) widget. In a `create()` method or in the constructor,  add a *layout*( or *container*) widget to the parent widget, then inset the others into the container.  Now threat this new subclass as if it were a single, but specialized, version of its super class.

A `Window` is an example of a parent widget, while  `Fixed` is an example container. A child could be an `EventBox` enclosing an `Image`.  The composite of all these is a new window object that has pictures that can be clicked.

For the case of a window's  *titlebar* look with a pixmap background, and buttons, try a `Window` with an `Image` and a `Fixed` container to hold the buttons. The `Fixed` and the `Image` should be able to overlap as the `Fixed` is transparent, and an `Image` has no `Window`.

If `Buttons` are truly what's needed, have a look at *Button Boxes* and  *Toolbars* in the list of [GTK Containers](http://www.gtk.org/tutorial1.2/gtk_tut.html#toc10). It may be possible to add an `Image` background to one of those.

A different approach involves an *Alignment Widget*(from the same list). It specifies where the smaller widgets are positioned and sized in a proportioned manner.

I assumed, OOP, but if it's not, just organize the creation of the widgets from one function. I've made composite widgets  functionally in Haskell(*Gtk2Hs*), and in *Guile Gnome Platform* (with and without OOP)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `Fixed`!